# How do i submit form data using jquery-ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure why I'm not getting it. Either way this is frustrating me beyond belief. I've looked through 2 jquery books, web tutorials, and stack overflow posts and i still dont understand.

I am trying to build a search filter bar where a user can select filters and upon clicking "refine result" it modifies the query output.

How do I submit the value of whichever form radio box the user selects using jquery/ajax to a php page which will display results dependent upon the input, without page refresh.

1. Form-->
2. user selects radio button value and clicks submit-->
3. form data gets sent via jquery/ajax to the .php page whose output is to be displayed in  without page refresh-->
4. .php file processes the user input and creates output based on it

I've honestly looked through alot of different answers but all of them assume that the reader has a greater basic knowledge of javascript/jquery than I do.

Like, do I have to put the jQuery/ajax in a function that runs "onclick" of my submit button? Or do I just add a `.click` event handler for my button id?

Can someone explain it all to me assuming I'm a complete jQuery/ajax noob?

Comment: Have a look at jQuery ajax: api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and event bindings on the same site. They are showing basic examples. Reading the doc and beginner books can't be made any more basic as far as I know. If you have difficulties understanding JavaScript in general you have to look at some books or on-line resources on that too.

Comment: Do you have any experience with javascript?

Comment: I have basic experience in terms of basic syntax, making/calling functions, referencing parts of the DOM etc. which i was hoping would be enough... but maybe a weak foundation in js is making jquery/ajax comprehension untenable at this point

Comment: Thank you Francois, i guess i'll just have to be more patient. Sometimes it's hard :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to attach your ajax call to the "submit" event that comes from the form when the submit button is clicked :

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content').load(this.action+" .content", $(this).serialize(), function(){
        // code to execute after result display if needed
    });
    return false;
});
```

I assumed your results are displayed in an element that has the "content" class.

1. `$('form')` selects your form, you can personalize it
2. `.submit` attach an event handler to the form "submit event
3. `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` prevents the form to be actually submitted
4. `$('.content').load` will fill the element with "content" class with the ajax call results
5. `this.action` is the URL to submit the form to
6. `" +.content"` is here to extract only the result part from the response, instead of the entire html page
7. `$(this).serialize()` passes the form fields data to the ajax request
8. finally the last anonymous function is called after the results are displayed and can be used to trigger some visual effect indicating that the results were updated

Comment: That's exactly what i needed. Everything is clearer now, thank you! :)